# Flask: get error 404 when I try to access index

Tags: python, flask, routes, http-status-code-404

when I run the Flask Server with **flask run**, I get error 404 in the Index Page.

```
 * Serving Flask app "sf.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2021 10:25:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
> manually please check your spelling and try again.

- Project Structure

```
.
├── app
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── clients
│   └── client.py
├── migrations
├── tests
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── test_models.py
│   ├── test_client.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── publisher.py
├── manage.py
├── run_client.py
├── requirements.txt
└── sf.py
```

- `/sf.py`

```py
from app import create_app


create_app()
```

- `/app/__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from . models import db


POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'sf',
    'pw': 'sf',
    'db': 'sf',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
}


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(app)

    return app


from app import routes
```

- `/app/routes.py`

```py
from app import create_app
from app.models import Area, Sensor, Monitoring

from flask import request, jsonify
from flask.views import MethodView


app = create_app()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

...
```

I need to use the `create_app()` because I need an that the `/clients/client.py` use the app.

- `/clients/client.py`

```py
from paho.mqtt.client import Client
import json

from app import create_app
from app.models import db

from app.models import Monitoring


app = create_app()


class CustomClient(Client):

    def add_reading(self, reading):
        with app.app_context():
            db.session.add(reading)
            db.session.commit()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print(
            "Connected:", 
            str(client._host) + ":" + str(client._port)
        )

    def on_subscribe(self, mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        print(
            "Subscribed:", 
            str(mid), str(granted_qos)
        )

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        msg = message.payload.decode()
        print(message.topic, msg)
        data = json.loads(msg)
        reading = Monitoring(**data)

        self.add_reading(reading)

    def run(self):
        self.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)
        self.subscribe("Main/#", 0)

        self.loop_forever()
```

But in this way I get the 404 error. And I'm not sure that I'm using the app properly. It would be fine to have an app and a db session separate, to test models and client without care the app configuration (probably I need to create a separate config for test?). What I've missed?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating **three** instances of the `Flask()` object. One is created in `sf.py`, the others in `routes.py` and `client.py`. The first one is used to serve the site, and so doesn't have your route, because the route is registered with the instance created in `routes.py`. The 3rd instance, in `client.py` is independent and isn't further altered, so is not an issue here; more on that below.

Don't create multiple copies, at least not *and* alter the registrations on one and expect those to be available on the other. Instead, use [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/) to register your views, and then register the blueprint with the `Flask()` object in your `create_app()` function. That way you can decouple registration of your routes from creating the `Flask()` object, and still get your routes registered centrally.

In your `routes.py`, use:

```
from app.models import Area, Sensor, Monitoring

from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
from flask.views import MethodView

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

# ...
```

and then import that blueprint in `create_app()`:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(app)

    from . import routes
    app.register_blueprint(routes.bp)

    return app
```

The reason you want to do the import in `create_app()` is that in most Flask applications you'll also be using one or more Flask extensions that are generally created outside of `create_app()` so your views can import them. You'd get a circular import if you tried to import one of those objects in your `routes` module if your `routes` module was imported into `app.py` at the top level.

With this change (to using a blueprint), you avoid creating a separate `Flask()` instance with registrations that the main instance, used for serving your site, won't see. Even your `client.py` process will be able to access those routes now, should there be a need (e.g. if you need to generate URLs with `url_for()`).

Here is an example from an in-production Flask project I built for a client recently, the `app.py` module contains, in part, the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_babel import Babel
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


babel = Babel()
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
migrate = Migrate()
security = Security()


_app_init_hooks = []
app_init_hook = _app_init_hooks.append


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    for f in _app_init_hooks:
        f(app)

    return app


@app_init_hook
def _configure(app):
    """Load Flask configurations"""

    app.config.from_object(f"{__package__}.config")

    # optional local overrides
    app.config.from_pyfile("settings.cfg", silent=True)
    app.config.from_envvar("PROJECT_NAME_SETTINGS", silent=True)


@app_init_hook
def _init_extensions(app):
    """Initialise Flask extensions"""

    if app.env != "production":
        # Only load and enable when in debug mode
        from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

        DebugToolbarExtension(app)

    # Python-level i18n
    babel.init_app(app)

    # Database management (models, migrations, users)
    from .models import Role, User

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security.init_app(app, user_datastore)

    # Marshmallow integration (must run after db.init_app())
    ma.init_app(app)


@app_init_hook
def _setup_blueprints(app):
    """Import and initialise blueprints"""

    from . import users
    from .sections import BLUEPRINTS

    for blueprint in (*BLUEPRINTS, users.bp):
        app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

    return app
```

I've broken up the various components into separate functions to ease readability and maintainability, there are separate blueprints used for distinct site functions (which drives some automation in the UI).

At the top of the module are several Flask extensions that various routes and other modules need access to without having to worry about circular imports, so the blueprints are imported separately inside of the `_setup_blueprints()` hook function that is called from `create_app()`.

Your use of `create_app()` in `client.py` should be fine because it doesn't add any new configuration to the `Flask()` instance that you'd want to have access to elsewhere, and presumably `client.py` is used outside of the Flask webserver process. But I would, personally, just make the result of `create_app()`an instance attribute of your `Client` instance. You don't need a global there, you only need it to access the database session easily for when `add_reading()` is called:

```
class CustomClient(Client):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs):
        # Create a Flask context so we can access the SQLAlchemy session
        self._app = create_app()

    def add_reading(self, reading):
        with self._app.app_context():
            db.session.add(reading)
            db.session.commit()

    # ...
```

If `add_reading()` is called very frequently, you could consider making `app` an instance attribute of `CustomClient()`:

Comment: Thank you! But for the client.py, that is running independently from the app, I need to create a new Flask instance? Because I see the client.py like a separated thread (or job).

Comment: @EdoardoZucchelli: yes, because in that process there is no Flask instance to access the usual way (e.g. with `current_app`). So you are correct that you need to call `create_app()` there. There are other ways to get access to the SQLAlchemy session and models, but this way _is_ easier.